# finding basic conditional probability function and conditional mean

Tags: probability, statistics, discrete-mathematics

i am stuck on this question and don't know how to solve it. would really appreciate your help with it:

we toss a regular coin 50 times:

$X$ - the number of heads from 50 tosses.

$Y$ - the number of heads from the first 20 tosses.

1) find the conditional probability function of Y if given that X=i for {i=0,...,50}, and the conditional probability function of X if given Y=j so that {j=0,...,20}

2) calculate $E[X\mid Y =j]$

what i tried to do:

1)in order to find the conditional probability function, we have to use $P_{X|Y}(x \mid y) =\frac{P_{XY}{(x,y)}}{p_Y(y)}$, however, since it's cumulative it becomes:$ P_{X\mid Y}(x \mid y)  = P(X ≤ x \mid Y = y)$, which means that in order to find the conditional probability function of Y if given that X=i, we have to calculate $P_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)=P(X≤50\mid Y=y)$, and to calculate the other (the conditional probability function of X if given Y=j so that {j=0,...,20}) we have to calculate $P_{X\mid Y}(x\mid y)=P(Y≤20\mid X=X)$. however i'm not sure how to continue the calculation to find the needed conditional probability functions

2)it seems easier: in order to find $E[X\mid Y =j]$, i have to calculate $\sum_x x p_{(X\mid Y)}(x\mid y)$ which is actually equivalent to using the integral $\int x f_{x\mid y} (x\mid y)$. however, i don't know how to calculate $f_{x\mid y}(x\mid y)$ to be able to calculate the conditional mean.

could you please help me with that or correct me if what i did is wrong?

thank you very much, tried to elaborate as much as i can. would appreciate your help learning how to calculate it correctly

Answer (score 1):

Tip: The count of heads among the first 20 tosses and the count of heads among the last 30 are *independent random variables*.   Also both are binomially distributed, although *not* identically.

So, let $Z=X-Y$, then $P_{X,Y}(x,y)=P_{Z}(x-y)\cdot P_Y(y)$

Therefore ...

---

For (b) $\mathsf E(X\mid Y=j)=\mathsf E(Z+Y\mid Y=j)$, so...

Comment: couldn't solve it. i am getting into a huge mess and would appreciate to see a correct and efficient way to solve it

Comment: What exactly is the trouble?

Comment: for finding the conditional probability function of y give x=i $P_{X|Y}(x \mid y) =\frac{P_{XY}{(x,y)}}{p_Y(y)}$ i got using your tip that it equals to $p_Z(x-y)$. however, i am not sure how to use it for the latter, finding the conditional probability function of x given y=i

Comment: @BeginningMath Likewise: $\mathsf P_{Y\mid X}(y\mid x) = \dfrac{\mathsf P_{X,Y}(x,y)}{\mathsf P_X(x)} =\ldots$